# WPF MVVM problem with ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a problem in adding and deleting items of `ObservableCollection`. After clicking on binded buttons, SQL Server database successfully updates, but after calling methods `WorkerInfoCollection.Add` and `WorkerInfoCollection.Remove` UI isn't updating. Moreover, `WorkerInfoCollection.Remove(SelectedWorker)` doesn't remove item at all. I can remove this item only if I use LINQ First or Default, but still - there are no changes in UI.

Through many hours of debugging and web searching, I've tried to change buttons Command Parameters: `ElementName` and `Path`, using `RelativeSource:AncestorType`, setting Command value in ViewModel constructor, setting Command value in setter, raise `OnPropertyChanged` in `ObservableCollection`, used different modes of Binding, adding and removing items from `ObservableCollection`, even tried to reinitialize `ObservableCollection` and fill it directly from database at runtime (kinda stupid). Nothing helped. Searching in web also didn't help the situation.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="WorkerInfoData" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Margin="10,10,50,10" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding WorkerInfoCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWorker,
                                     Mode=TwoWay}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID робітника" 
                                Binding="{Binding WorkerId}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Фото"
                                    Width="SizeToCells" 
                                    IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding WorkerPhoto}"
                               Height="75"
                               Width="75"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill"
                               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ПІБ" 
                                Binding="{Binding WorkerFullName}" />

            <...>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Хоббі" 
                                Binding="{Binding WorkerHobby}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="3" 
                Name="addRecordPanel" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                Margin="0,0,-369,0" 
                Width="417"
                DataContext="{Binding NewWorker,
                                      Mode=TwoWay}">
        <Grid>
            <Button Name="buttonHideAddRecordPanel" 
                    Width="48" 
                    Height="48" 
                    Click="ButtonHideAddRecordPanel_Click" 
                    Visibility="Hidden"
                    Margin="0 0 0 100">
                <Button.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                </Button.Background>
                <Image Source="Images/ClosePanel.png" 
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Name="buttonShowAddRecordPanel"
                    Height="48"
                    Width="48" 
                    Click="ButtonShowAddRecordPanel_Click"
                    Margin="0 0 0 100">
                <Button.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                </Button.Background>
                <Image Source="Images/AddRecord.ico" 
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
                BorderThickness="1.5" 
                Width="369" 
                Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 10"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <TextBlock Text="Дані нового робітника" 
                               FontSize="16"
                               Background="Gainsboro"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="0"
                               Padding="0 0 0 3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="ID робітника"
                               Margin="0 10 0 0"/>
                    <TextBox   Text="{Binding WorkerId,

       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                               Margin="0 5"
                               Width="300"
                               Background="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Фото робітника" 
                               Margin="0 5 0 0"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Width="300"
                            Margin="0 5 0 0">
                        <Image Source="{Binding WorkerPhoto, 

         NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,

         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                                Converter= 
         {conv:ByteToImage}}" 
                               Height="300"
                               Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Button Name="AddNewWorkerPhoto" 
                            Width="150" 
                            FontSize="14" 
                            Content="Завантажити фото" 
                            Command="{Binding AddRecordImage}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding 
         ElementName=addRecordPanel, 

         Path=DataContext}">
                        <Button.DataContext>
                            <VM:WorkerInfoViewModel/>
                        </Button.DataContext>
                    </Button>

                   <...>

                    <Button Name="AddRecord"
                            Content="Додати запис"
                            FontSize="14"
                            Width="150" 
                            Margin="0 10"
                            Command="{Binding AddRecord}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding 
            ElementName=addRecordPanel, 

            Path=DataContext}">
                        <Button.DataContext>
                            <VM:WorkerInfoViewModel/>
                        </Button.DataContext>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="3"
                Name="deleteRecordPanel"
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                Margin="0,0,-369,0" 
                Width="417">
        <Grid>
            <Button Name="DeleteRecord"
                    Height="48"
                    Width="48" 
                    Margin="0 100 0 0"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteRecord}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding 
                ElementName=WorkerInfoData, 
                                               Path=SelectedItem}">
                <Button.DataContext>
                    <VM:WorkerInfoViewModel/>
                </Button.DataContext>
                <Button.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                </Button.Background>
                <Image Source="Images/DeleteRecord.png" 
                       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

WorkerInfo.cs

```
      public class WorkerInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
      {
             private int workerId;
      <...>
      public int WorkerId
      {
        get { return workerId; }
        set
        {
            workerId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WorkerId));
        }

      <...>

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
        PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> 
    canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        execute(parameter);
    }
   }
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
  PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

WorkerInfoViewModel.cs

```
 public class WorkerInfoViewModel : ViewModelBase
 {
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private DataTable dataTable;
    private WorkerInfo newWorker;
    private WorkerInfo selectedWorker;

    public WorkerInfo NewWorker
    {
        get
        {
            if (newWorker == null)
            {
                return newWorker = new WorkerInfo();
            }
            else return newWorker;
        }
        set
        {
            newWorker = value;
        }
    }
    public WorkerInfo SelectedWorker
    {
        get { return selectedWorker; }
        set
        {
            selectedWorker = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedWorker");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<WorkerInfo> workerInfoCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<WorkerInfo> WorkerInfoCollection
    {
        get { return workerInfoCollection; }
        set
        {
            workerInfoCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WorkerInfoCollection");
        }

    }

    public ICommand AddRecord { get; }
    public ICommand AddRecordImage { get; }
    public ICommand UpdateRecord { get; }
    public ICommand UpdateRecordImage { get; }

    private ICommand deleteCommand;
    public ICommand DeleteRecord
    {
        get
        {
            if (deleteCommand == null)
            {
                deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
        DeleteRecord_Click(parameter));
            }
            return deleteCommand;
        }
    }


    public WorkerInfoViewModel()
    {
        string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [WorkerInfo]";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new 
             SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, 
            connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                    WorkerInfoCollection = new 
              ObservableCollection<WorkerInfo>();
                    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        WorkerInfoCollection.Add
                            (
                               new WorkerInfo()
                               {
                                   WorkerId = 
                 Convert.ToInt32(dataRow["WorkerId"]),

                 <...>
                                   WorkerHobby = 
                dataRow["WorkerHobby"].ToString()
                               }
                            );
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        AddRecord = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
             AddRecord_Click(parameter));
        AddRecordImage = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
                  AddWorkerPhoto_Click(parameter));

        UpdateRecord = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
                   UpdateRecord_Click(parameter));
        UpdateRecordImage = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
             UpdateWorkerPhoto_Click(parameter));

        //DeleteRecord = new RelayCommand(parameter => 
                DeleteRecord_Click(parameter));
    }


    private void AddRecord_Click(object parameter)
    {
        NewWorker = (WorkerInfo)parameter;

        WorkerInfoCollection.Add
            (
                new WorkerInfo()
                {
                    WorkerId = NewWorker.WorkerId,
                    <...>
                    WorkerHobby = NewWorker.WorkerHobby
                }
            );


        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [WorkerInfo] (" +
                "WorkerId, " +
                    <...>
                "@WorkerHobby)";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new 
            SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, 
               connection))
            {
                try
                {

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkerId", 
                NewWorker.WorkerId);

                    <...>

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkerHobby", 
              NewWorker.WorkerHobby);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");

                    log.Error(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void DeleteRecord_Click(object parameter)
    {
        SelectedWorker = (WorkerInfo)parameter;

        string deleteRecord = "DELETE FROM [WorkerInfo] " +
                              "WHERE WorkerId = @WorkerId";

        if (SelectedWorker != null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new 
           SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(deleteRecord, 
               connection))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkerId", 
              SelectedWorker.WorkerId);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        connection.Close();

                        WorkerInfoCollection.Remove(SelectedWorker);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("error");

                        log.Error(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered that `connection.Close()` is throwing an error, causing the Remove line to be skipped?

Comment: You are setting different instances of view models for each button. So, the button commands get invoked on seperate instance than the one which provides the list to `DataTable`. What are you trying to achieve by setting `<Button.DataContext>
                    <VM:WorkerInfoViewModel/>
                </Button.DataContext>` ?

Comment: heap1 Thank you for your answer. I placed line WorkerInfoCollection.Remove higher than using block, but it didn't help the situation. 
About restructuring code - I'll do it as soon as I possible.

Comment: Mat J Thank you for you reply. I am new to MVVM pattern. When my button not responded on clicking, I've searched for solution and found this as a resolvement of my problem. I didn`t realize, that I created new instances of ViewModel.

Comment: Mat J UPD: You were right. Thank you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
          <Button.DataContext>
                <VM:WorkerInfoViewModel/>
            </Button.DataContext>
```

That instantiates another instance of workerinfo viewmodel.

Remove that.

You want to be adding and removing from the same observablecollection in the same viewmodel instance the itemssource of your datagrid is bound to.

As it is, you have at least 3 instances of that viewmodel.

Make sure you just have the one instance of your viewmodel and that is the datacontext of mainwindow and hence the buttons and datagrid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I answered to Mat J, I didn`t realize, that I created new instances of ViewModels. I'll edit my code according to your comment.